# Envio de email .php não redireciona página

Tags: php

Esse script tem por finalidade pegar os dados de um ActionScript e enviar via email, contudo, ele não esta retornando uma mensagem de sucesso(ou erro) ao usuário. Mesmo o email sendo enviado... preciso que ele emita um Pop-up alertando sobre o sucesso do envio ou redireciona para um .html

```
<?php
/*if(!isset($_POST[Submit])) die("N&atilde;o recebi nenhum par&acitc;metro. Por favor volte ao formulario.html antes");
/* Medida preventiva para evitar que outros domínios sejam remetente da sua mensagem. */

@extract($_POST);

if (preg_match('tempsite.ws$|locaweb.com.br$|hospedagemdesites.ws$|websiteseguro.com$', $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST])) {
        $emailsender='contato@fenytuniformes.com.br';
} else {
        $emailsender = "webmaster@" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
        //    Na linha acima estamos forçando que o remetente seja 'webmaster@seudominio',
        // você pode alterar para que o remetente seja, por exemplo, 'contato@seudominio'.
}

/* Verifica qual é o sistema operacional do servidor para ajustar o cabeçalho de forma correta. Não alterar */
if(PHP_OS == "Linux") $quebra_linha = "\n"; //Se for Linux
elseif(PHP_OS == "WINNT") $quebra_linha = "\r\n"; // Se for Windows
else die("Este script nao esta preparado para funcionar com o sistema operacional de seu servidor");

// Passando os dados obtidos pelo formulário para as variáveis abaixo
/*
$nomeremetente          = $_POST["nome"];
$emailremetente         = trim($_POST["email"]);
$telefoneremetente      = trim($_POST["telefone"]);
$cidaderemetente        = trim($_POST["cidade"]);
$cepremetente           = trim($_POST["cep"]);
$observacaoremetente    = trim($_POST["observacoes"]);

$comcopia               = trim($_POST["comcopia"]);
$comcopiaoculta         = trim($_POST["comcopiaoculta"]);

$referencia             = $_POST["referencia"];
$gola1                  = $_POST["gola1"];
$pato                   = $_POST["pato"];
$manga                  = $_POST["manga"];
$mangaesquerda          = $_POST["mangaesquerda"];
$manga2                 = $_POST["manga2"];
$recort1                = $_POST["recort1"];
$recort2                = $_POST["recort2"];
$recort3                = $_POST["recort3"];
$punho                  = $_POST["punho"];
$galao1                 = $_POST["galao1"];
$galao2                 = $_POST["galao2"];
$logo1                  = $_POST["logo1"];
*/


$nomeremetente          = $_POST["nome"];
$emaildestinatario      = "alexandreberrantinho@gmail.com";

/* Montando a mensagem a ser enviada no corpo do e-mail. */
$mensagemHTML= "<P>MENSAGEM DE E-MAIL ENVIADO POR FENYT UNIFORMES - PERSONALIZAÇÃO</P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P><hr></P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Nome: $nome\n";
$mensagemHTML.= "E-Mail: $email\n";
$mensagemHTML.= "Telefone: $telefone\n";
$mensagemHTML.= "Cidade: $cidade\n";
$mensagemHTML.= "Cep: $cep\n";
$mensagemHTML.= "Observações: $observacoes\n";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P><hr></P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P><hr></P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P>PERSONALIZAÇÃO</P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P><hr></P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Referencia: $referencia\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Gola: $gola1\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Corpo: $pato\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Mangas: $manga\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Manga Esquerda: $mangaesquerda\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Manga Direita: $manga2\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Recorte 1: $recort1\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Recorte 2: $recort2\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Recorte 3: $recort3\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Punho: $punho\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Galão 1: $galao1\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Galão 2: $galao2\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Logo: $logo1\n <br>";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P><hr></P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "<P>Avental</P>";
$mensagemHTML.= "Bolso: $bolso\n";


/* Montando o cabeçalho da mensagem */
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha;
// Perceba que a linha acima contém "text/html", sem essa linha, a mensagem não chegará formatada.
$headers .= "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailsender . $quebra_linha;
// Esses dois "if's" abaixo são porque o Postfix obriga que se um cabeçalho for especificado, deverá haver um valor.
// Se não houver um valor, o item não deverá ser especificado.
if(strlen($comcopia) > 0) $headers .= "Cc: ".$comcopia.$quebra_linha;
if(strlen($comcopiaoculta) > 0) $headers .= "Bcc: ".$comcopiaoculta.$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$emailremetente.$quebra_linha;
// Note que o e-mail do remetente será usado no campo Reply-To (Responder Para)

/* Enviando a mensagem */
$envio = mail($emaildestinatario, $nomeremetente, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $emailsender);

/* Mostrando na tela as informações enviadas por e-mail */
if($envio){
    include("enviosucesso.html");
}
else{
 include("envioerro.html");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript **não interpreta HTML**, ao menos não com `URLLoader` diretamente (por padrão), portanto `enviosucesso.html` ou `envioerro.html` não vão funcionar.

O máximo que vai conseguir para fazer o ActionScript interpretar o HTML é usar algo como https://github.com/talltyler/HTMLWrapper, claro que a parte do form você vai ter que reimplementar (se estiver usando Adobe AIR e não Adobe Flash dá para implementar um webView, mas ai creio que a história seja outra).

Para resolver depende muito de como você usou o ActionScript, se foi mesmo `URLLoader` ele só vai interpretar strings da resposta do servidor em um formato semelhante as querystrings, por exemplo:

```
foo=1&bar=true
```

Supondo que fez algo semelhante a isto:

```
function enviarFormulario(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://[site]/envia.php");
  urlreq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

  var urlvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
  urlvars.nome = camponome.text;
  urlvars.email = campoemail.text;
  urlvars.score = campomensagem.text;

  urlreq.data = urlvars;

  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlreq); 
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completed); 
  loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
  loader.load(urlreq); 
}

function completed(event:Event):void
{
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
    camporesposta.text = variables.resposta;
}

botaosubmit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enviarFormulario);
```

Veja que `variables.resposta` contém o `.resposta`, quer dizer que no php terá que ter algo assim:

```
if($envio){
     echo 'resposta=sucesso';
} else{
     echo 'resposta=erro+ao+enviar';
}
```

### Outros detalhes:

- O `camporesposta.text` se refere a alguma label que você deve ter ou criar para receber o texto de resposta da variavel
- `camponome.text`, `campoemail.text` e `campomensagem.text` são campos hipotéticos que se referem ao seu formulário
- `botaosubmit.addEventListener` se refere ao movieClip ou botão mesmo que você tem no formulário.
- Não use a variavel no PHP assim `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`, use assim `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, sem as aspas o PHP primeiro vai procurar uma **constante** chamada `HTTP_HOST` que claro que não existe, então vai emitir um warning, no output ou no arquivo de log e só depois ele irá converter `HTTP_HOST` para uma `string` e assim passar a funcionar, ou seja o seu log de erros irá conter uma série de erros repetidos sobre isto, deve ficar assim:

  ```
  if (preg_match('tempsite.ws$|locaweb.com.br$|hospedagemdesites.ws$|websiteseguro.com$', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
          $emailsender='contato@fenytuniformes.com.br';
  } else {
          $emailsender = "webmaster@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
          //    Na linha acima estamos forçando que o remetente seja 'webmaster@seudominio',
          // você pode alterar para que o remetente seja, por exemplo, 'contato@seudominio'.
  }
  ```